# Pymongo MapReduce as sum of subarray element

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

I'm trying to perform MapReduce on this kind of data set:

```
 {
"_id": "599861ce7ce78cd973746906",
"name": "Macias Rosario",
"col": [
  {
    "date": "15/03/2016",
    "name": "MAGNEATO",
    "amount": 313.86
  },
  {
    "date": "08/08/2016",
    "name": "FORTEAN",
    "amount": 151.06
  },
  {
    "date": "05/11/2014",
    "name": "ECRATIC",
    "amount": 291.68
  }
]
```

}

Goal is to sum up all **amount** for name **Macias Rosario**. Currently I did with my code to group all by subelements `this.col.name` on this way:

```
mapper = Code("""
                           function() {   
                           for (var index = 0; index < this.col.length; ++index) {
                                var col = this.col[index];
                                emit(col.name, col.amount );
                            }   
                           }
                           """)
        reducer = Code("""
                           function(key, values) {
                               var total =  0;
                               for( var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i){
                                    total += values[i];


                               }
                               return value.price;
                           }
               """)
        result = collection.map_reduce(mapper, reducer, "myresult")
```

Has anyone have some idea how to reference, or group by `this.name` and not `this.col.name` because I don't know anymore and I'm driving nuts?
PS don't suggest me to use `aggregate`, did that way, want to try on this way also :)
Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code helps (works in pymongo as well)

This is my map function:

```
var mapFunction = function() {
    for (var idx = 0; idx < this.col.length; idx++) {
        var key = this.name;
        var value = { amount : this.col[idx].amount };
        emit(key, value);
   } 
};
```

And the following is my reduce function:

```
var reduceFunction = function(key, amountVl) {
    reduceVal = { amount : 0 };
    for (var idx = 0; idx < amountVl.length; idx++) {
        reduceVal.amount += amountVl[idx].amount; 
    }
    return reduceVal;
}
```

With your sample data it produces:

```
{ "_id" : "Macias Rosario", "value" : { "amount" : 756.6 } }
```